# Ajax and func_get_args()

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Is it possible to use php's **func_get_args()** to catch 'post(ed)' data from an Ajax function call? (Currently using json to post data).

Hypothetical Ajax call posting data:

```
.
url: '.../.../...?action=function'
data: { someString: someString }
.
.
```

php:

```
function() {
  $arg_list = func_get_args();
  foreach( $arg_list as ....) {
  .
  .
  }
}
```

i'm currently using *isset( $_POST['someString'] )* but I was wondering if i can achieve the same using *func_get_args()*.

Currently, func_get_args isn't catching anything from the ajax call. The 'post' line is directly below this chunk of code and is verifying that ajax has correctly sent the function the correct data. However, func_get_args isn't actually displaying anything on a var_dump. What am i not doing?

Many Thanks

Comment: Congratulations! you have done it your self. Is there any other issue?

Comment: Hi Jai. func_get_args isnt actually working for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. `func_get_args()` looks for function arguments in php stack, while `$_POST` and `$_GET` look for http request header parameters.

But if you just want to iterate through $_POST parameters without knowing their names, try this:

```
foreach( $_POST as $pars ) { 
  if( is_array( $pars ) ) { 
    foreach( $pars as $par ) { 
      echo $par; 
    } 
  } 
  else { echo $pars; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Ok. Is there any other way of capturing this data besides $_POST? Something similar to func_get_args without haing any parameter requirements in the function.

Comment: $_REQUEST stores all get, post and cookie parameters. But if you just want to iterate through $_POST parameters without knowing their names, try this:

`foreach( $_POST as $pars ) {
    if( is_array( $pars ) ) {
        foreach( $pars as $par ) {
            echo $par;
        }
    } else {
        echo $pars;
    }
}`

Comment: I was actually trying to get rid of post altogether but i don't think this is possible from your answer about ajax posting to headers and func_get_args only looking at the php stack. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like that :

```
function myAjaxFunction() {
    $args = $_POST;

    if (sizeof($args) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($arg_list as $arg) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help.